# Static fields or const functions for util methods?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a set of reusable validators.

Is it better to declare them as static const functions ?

```
export const emailValidator: ValidatorFn = 
  function(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return [...];
  };

export const anotherValidator: ValidatorFn = 
  function(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return [...];
  };
```

or as static methods of a non-instantiable class ?

```
class CustomValidators {

  static emailValidator = 
    function(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
      return [...];
    }

  static anotherValidator = 
    function(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
      return [...];
    }
}
```

The 2nd solution looks nice because I will be able to use `CustomValidators.*` and autocomplete but it seems "ugly" to create a class that will actually never be instantiated. I use it more as a namespace.

Also, does it have consequences on tree shaking ? Will unused validators be suppressed at build time ?

Answer (score 1):

The static objects will always remain on the javascript emitted bundle to be readily available for use as objects. if you want you can write those in util functions which may create the validators on demand instead of preinitializing them as static objects.
The other way is instead create a namespace and initialize on demand.